# Using images to make a border CSS3

Tags: html, css, border, frame

I am looking for advice and possibly links to any tutorials which deal with styling CSS3 borders with images. I am looking to create a dynamic frame around a div that will expand to fit any image I place inside it:

I desire an effect similar to this:

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/1zvykjl.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

You can see an article on border-image css3 property [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-border-images/). But i'm not sure, that you can accomplish your result because of differences between your images.